# Rails 4 and referencing parent id in 'has_many' SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

*TL;DR:* How do I use the ID of the respective parent object in a has_many SQL clause to find child objects?

*Long version:*
I have the following example code:

```
class Person < AR::Base
  has_many :purchases, -> { 
    "SELECT * from purchases
      WHERE purchase.seller_id = #{id}
         OR purchase.buyer_id = #{id}"
  }
```

This was migrated from Rails 3 which worked and looked like

```
  has_many :purchases, :finder_sql => proc { #same SQL as above# }
```

I want to find all purchases associated with a Person object in one association, no matter whether the person was the one selling the object or buying it.

**Update:** I corrected the SQL, it was inside out. Sorry! Also: The association only needs to be read-only: I am never going to create records using this association, so using `id` twice should be OK. But I *do* want to be able to chain other scopes on it, e.g. `@person.purchases.paid.last_5`, so creating the sum of two associations in a method does not work (at least it didn't in Rails 3) since it doesn't return an AM::Relation but a simple Array.

When using this above definition in Rails 4.2, I get

```
> Person.first.purchases
undefined method `id' for #<Person::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x...>
```

The error is clear, but then how do I solve the problem?

Since this is only an example for much more complicated SQL code being used to express has_many relationships (e.g. multiple JOINS with subselects for performance), the question is:

How do I use the ID of the parent object in a has_many SQL clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your code will work at all. You are defining an association with two foreign keys ... that'd mean that in case you want to create a new `Person` from a present `Purchase`, what foreign key is to be used, `seller_id` or `buyer_id`? That just don't make sense.

In any case, the error you are getting is clear: you are calling a variable `id` which is not initialized in the block context of the SQL code.

A better approach to the problem I understand from your question would be to use associations in the following way, and then define a  method that gives you all the persons, both buyers and sellers that a product has. Something like this:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'Person'

  def persons
    ids = (buyer_ids + seller_ids).uniq
    Person.where(ids: id)
  end 
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sold_purchases, class_name: 'Purchase', foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :buyed_purchases, class_name: 'Purchase', foreign_key: 'seller_id'
end
```

Im my approach, `buyer_id` and `seller_id` are purchase's attributes, not person's.

I may have not understood correctly, in that case please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, my code was messed up, I corrected it above. A separate method is what I tried to use about four years ago when the project started using Rails 2.3. But since I want to be able to chain other scopes on @purchase.persons (see edit), this doesn't really work (and never did). I need a "real" association object.

Comment: If you need scopes you could do it with my edit as well

Comment: True, thank you, this works but it requires three SQL round trips for `persons`), one of which can be a rather long SQL string depending on how many `_ids` there are. I wonder if this can be done in one SQL command ... :)

Comment: I decided I will just use a method (like `persons` above but without the scopes - after all I don't need most of the features an association gives you). I guess associations are simply not the right tool for what I want to achieve.  Thank you for making me stop and think again .. :)